# Java scheduled thread pool executor with initial delay on some condition check on some value

Tags: java, multithreading, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

Issue:

I have a task which has to be run periodically with a fixed delay after each task is run. Also i have a condition
where in the initial delay or the first time execution should occur after a condition is met . So the executor must 
prevent scheduling task until the condition is meet.

Java Concurrent package gives us ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor which has option for initial delay in time. But in my case 
the initial delay is after some condition or value changes to desired one.

How can i achieve this behavior and what executorservice should i use or what methods in executor service can i override to achieve above behavior.

I don't want to start creating the ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor object only after the condition is meet , reason being that
there are large number of such periodic scheduled tasks which are present in our application and if any new task is added next time
and if they forget to added in code part where the check is made then it will be scheduled immediately without any condition check. 
To avoid it i wanted an executor service which will handle it for me and next time anyone using this executorservice will by default get this 
behavior for free.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will find readymade ExecutorService to handle your use-case. So why not try like this, create your custom class which extends ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor and there you override the `beforeExecute` method and here you write code to check for first time execution (have custom flag to check is it first execution or not) and than for other calls it will execute normal runnable object. Something similar to below code :

```
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class TestClass extends ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor {

public TestClass(int corePoolSize) {
    super(corePoolSize);
}

@Override
protected void beforeExecute(Thread t, Runnable r) {
    super.beforeExecute(t, r);
}

@Override
public ScheduledFuture<?> scheduleAtFixedRate(Runnable command, long initialDelay, long period, TimeUnit unit) {
    return super.schedule(command, initialDelay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you , even i was thinking on having hooks with beforeExecute to check for first time execution .  Is it better to wait for execution with loosing cpu cycle in before update or have code block check and execute the tasks only after condition is met?  Which way is better to have a maintainable codebase so developers need to worry that there is precondition check for all the future periodic tasks that are added.

Comment: Or is there a way to skip the execution in current cycle based on condition ? Should i do it inside the runnable or some hook in the executor ?

Answer (score 0):

How about you create your executor in advance but only perform an operation of scheduling of task on pre-existing executor after your condition is met and you already know your desired initial delay.

Comment: Thanks for your reply , wanted to see if i have executor service which serves above purpose so that next time any developer codes a new periodic task which has to wait on same condition then he can use the same executor service instead of he remembering that he has to add the task after the condition is met. Also do you think this approach of Executor service waiting cycle to check on condition is better or maintain the code and make sure the developers in your code are aware to add tasks only after condition ?

Comment: Perhaps you can have layered Executors. When your developer needs to submit the task he submits it to executor 1 who's job is periodically check if the condition for the job is true. When it is true the executor 1 will submit the job to executor 2 for periodic execution with known initial delay. After that executor 1 will its waiting job.

Comment: ended up using the same approach. Thanks